# OSX 12.3 - Test runner never began executing tests after launching

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, fastlane, test-runner

I'm executing some test on a xcode node with Fastlane and Scan and I randomly get this message:

```
Testing failed:
Project_UnitTests:
    The test runner encountered an error (Test runner never began executing tests after launching. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at DerivedData/Logs/Test/Run-Project_System-2021.04.08_02-00-23-+0200.xcresult)
** TEST FAILED **
ERROR [2021-04-08 03:01:14.15]: Exit status: 65
```

I've looked around to find the meaning of the error "Test runner never began executing tests after launching" but I could not find anything.

Could it be related to the fact that on the same machine may be excetuted multiple builds?

Thank you.

[SOLUTION] - I ended up understanding that we were using the same simulator for 2 build contemporarily and that caused the problem.
We created a mechanism that generate a new device each build from Jenkins.

Thank you all!

Comment: I got this too, trying to add xctests to a normal swift project, don't know why

Comment: Crazy, one device keeps having this problem, but it is fine on another device.